# Смена пароля ключа подписи .jks

Tags: android

Столкнулся с проблемой смены ключа подписи .jks. Ключ отлично работает если подписывать приложение внутри Android Studio, но не работает при подписи с помощью keytool. С паролем без кириллицы все работает отлично.
В пароле использовалась кириллица(спец. символ - keyPassword)

Пробовал поменять пароль с помощью keytool(через консоль) и программы **KeyStore Explorer**

```
keytool -keypasswd  -alias **** -keystore ****.jks
```

Не один из способов не увенчался успехом.

Ответ keytool

> keytool error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover
> key

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что можно было бы попробовать еще для смены пароля ?**

Comment: Кодировка. Не используйте кириллицу, либо разберитесь с кодировками.

Comment: Пробовал вставлять разные кодировки кириллического(Unicode Escape, Punycode IDN) пароля в консоль. Тоже не работает.